# How to close current window (in Code) when launching new Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
SignInWindow signIn= new SignInWindow();
signIn.ShowDialog();
```

The above code is in my MainWindow class.

When the new Window is shown, I want the current window to close. Whats the best way to do this?

My application is a C# WPF application

---

I've tries this but when it's called, my application exits

```
    static private void CloseAllWindows()
    {
        for (int intCounter = App.Current.Windows.Count - 1; intCounter >= 0; intCounter--)
            App.Current.Windows[intCounter].Close();
    }
```

Comment: In your window to close... this.Close(); or with a reference thatWindow.Close();

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just do this:

```
this.Close();
SignInWindow signIn = new SignInWindow();
signIn.ShowDialog();
```

bear in mind that will actually **close** the `MainWindow`. If all you're *really* trying to do is hide it, then do this:

```
this.Hide();
SignInWindow signIn = new SignInWindow();
signIn.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

That will *hide* the `MainWindow` while the login form is up, but then *show* it again when it's complete.

---

Okay, so apparently you're launching this form from a `static class` that is **outside** the form. That would have been pretty relevant information. But a solution would be this:

```
var w = Application.Current.Windows[0];
w.Hide();

SignInWindow signIn = new SignInWindow();
signIn.ShowDialog();

w.Show();
```

Comment: 'this' doesn't work in the WPF. I've thought about it because I used to do that in a WinForm.

Comment: @softwareisfun What do you mean by "'this' doesn't work in the WPF"? The `this` keyword is a C# language feature, entirely independent of whether or not you're using WPF. It refers to the current instance of the class from which it is called.

Comment: Error 1 Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

Comment: thats the error that comes up when I type it into my newly created XAML file. (There is no other code other than the one generated by Microsoft Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: @softwareisfun, it sounds like you're launching this other dialog from a different `class`. A `static class`. Would that be true?

Comment: public partial class MainWindow : Window

Comment: @softwareisfun, then you must have it executing in a `static` method. Either way, the last solution I provided should work just fine.

Comment: the method is a static method within the class.

Comment: If I hide the MainWindow, and I need to reference it from another class, how would I do that?

Comment: @softwareisfun, that's a real nebulous question. I don't know anything about this **other class.** Nor do I know if you can inject the reference or if you'll have to recover it. That sounds like an entirely different question at this point.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
SignInWindow signIn= new SignInWindow();
Application.Current.Windows[0].Close();
signIn.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I did this and the application exits. I am not 100% certain but it seems if i exit the MainWindow, the application stops. Anyway to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of redirection code. it will close current window/page and redirect to the new page/window in wpf

```
SignWindow sw = new SignWindow();
this.Content = sw;
```

Comment: I really liked this approach, but I wish it could be true for a Window. It may work for User Controls, but if you try to set a Window, you may get InvalidOperationException : 'Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Wndow as a child of Visual'.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Perrenoud's answer is 100% perfect, although you might want to create a object of the new window and activate it, before you close the Main Window.

Comment: This might be better suited to a comment on that "100% correct" answer, or maybe as an edit.

Comment: My reputation is not 50 to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following approach. Hide old/current window. Show new window and close the old window that is hidden. Following this approach application does not close.

```
SignInWindow signIn= new SignInWindow();
var oldWindow = Application.Current.Windows[0];
oldWindow.Hide(); 
signIn.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
oldWindow.Close();
```